# need a way to run mysqldump other than using system() function to backup

Tags: php, mysql, shared-hosting

I'm going to backup my database using a php script which executes a command using the `system()` function. Unfortunately, my shared hosting has disabled it. I got this warning when I ran it:

> Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons in /path-to-my-file on line 162

Here is my piece of code:

```
$filename = 'backup/mybackupfile.sql';
$command = "mysqldump -u myuser -pmypass mydatabase > ". $filename ."";
system($command);
```

It is working fine on my local computer with `xampp`, but it happens to be a problem on my shared hosting.

So, I need another way to run the `mysqldump` command instead of using `system()`. I try to avoid using **cron** or `SELECT * OUTFILE` things.

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to avoid using cron? That would be a proper solution.

Comment: `mysqldump` *is* a system command. If you can not fire system commands, what would you do? Rewrite that in PHP?

Comment: @hakra, decerée - is there some renaming meme going on that I'm not privy to? :)

Comment: @Matt > my user doesn't have access to cron, that's why I'm trying to avoid it

Comment: Then how are you running your backups on a schedule?

Comment: @hakra you mean, I should choose a more masculine user name? Pekkor? Pekkar? Hmm. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: @pekka, so there is no way out to run mysqldump in my host. so, can you share another solution to backup my database through php script?

Comment: @Asep I wrote up what I know below

Comment: @Matt, I do backup schedule with cron but my user what to do backups also anytime he want. So I need to provide a tool for him to do it :) Funny, he?

Comment: Shell script is probably the best way to go about it then. This way the user just has to run the file.

Comment: @Matt, well I'll think about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mrs. Hakra already said, you will not be able to run `mysqldump` at all if your host has disabled the execution of system commands.

You will have to ask them to enable system commands, or do a dump using a PHP script. Be very careful with the PHP dump scripts around, however: my experience has shown that many create broken or incomplete dumps.

Some Googling reveals small tools such as [this one](http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php). But as said, be careful and do some tests to verify accuracy.

The best PHP-based export tool I know that is doing the job properly is that of [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). Maybe that can help. In theory, it should even be possible to isolate its exporting library, but as far as I know it doesn't expose it in any easy way for use in other scripts.

Comment: yes, `phpmyadmin`is surely the best tool I know, but my client is not allowed to use it due to procedural matter. I think I will think about using more frequent schedule in cron instead. Thanks for your sharing ide :)